# Rails form object doesn't update database with polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I've searched and searched and nothing came up, so I need to ask you for help.
I have to create registration form with nesting fields with separate tables in database for user, company and address. Fields structure below (column names in db as follow):

```
User(new model)
 -first name
 -email
 Address(nested in User)
  -street
  -city
 Company(nested in User)
  - name
  - Address(nested in user.company)
    -street
    -city
```

The thing is that when I'm trying to save submit forms to the database I've got an error `unknown attribute 'company_name' for Company`. It shows me that my model has `name` attribute instead of `company_name` and it's true but how to associate them for company_name which is reflected to the :name column in company table? I think I should map my params but how to do so?

I associated them with polymorphic associations, my models are:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_one :address, as: :addressable
 has_one :company
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :address, as: :addressable

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

My registrations controller

```
def create
    @registration = Registration.new(registration_params)
end
private
  def registration_params
    params.require(:registration).permit(
      :first_name, :email,
      :street, :city,
      :company_street, :company_city
    )
  end
```

**forms/registration.rb**

```
class Registration
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :first_name, :email,
                :street, :city,
                :company_street, :company_city
  attr_reader :params

  def address_params
    params.slice(:street, :city, :zip_code, :country)
  end

  def create_company
    company.save(company_params)
  end

  def create_company_address
    company.create_address(company_address_params)
  end

private
  def company_params
    params.slice(:company_name)
  end

  def company_address_params
    params.slice(:company_street, :company_city)
  end
```

EDIT:
missing view:

```
      <%= simple_form_for(@registration, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

       <%= f.input :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email", class: "form-control" %>
       <%= f.input :first_name, class: "form-control" %>
       <%= f.input :street %>
       <%= f.input :city %>
       <%= f.input :zip_code %>
       <hr>
       <h3>Company details</h3>
       <%= f.input :company_name %>
       <%= f.input :company_street %>
       <%= f.input :company_city %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: you are not showing your form

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to read about how `accepts_nested_attributes_for` works and form's helper `fields_for`.

For the company with an addres, for example, you have to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` for the Company too on the User model and the form should be something like:

```
<h3>Company details</h3>
<%= f.simple_fields_for :company, Company.new do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.input :name %>
  <%= ff.simple_fields_for :address, Address.new do |fff| %>
    <%= fff.input :street %>
    <%= fff.input :city %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Then the parameters:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, company_attributes: [:name, address_attributes: [:street, :city])
end
```

I really recommend you to read about nested forms, `fields_for` method and the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` config on the models (and also about StrongParameters), it will make much more sense to my answer.